# udating prop after state of parent is updated and passes as the prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I pull data from firebase using

```
 componentWillMount(){//predi komponenta da se poqvi v DOM-a
      this.database.on('value', snap => {
        let snapData = snap.val();
        let allData = Object.keys(snapData).map(key => {
            return snapData[key];
        })
        let resultsData = Object.keys(snapData).map(key => {
            return snapData[key].result;
        })

        console.log(resultsData); // logs ["", 4, 1, 1, 2, "", 2, 0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 2, ""]

        this.setState({users:allData , results:resultsData},()=>console.log(this.state.results));
      });
}
```

later on, i pass `this.state.results` to  a component via `props`

```
<OmegaData results={this.state.results}/>
```

the problem is that the `OmegaData` renders to  early and this.state.results is formed too late .. in that case, the  `results` prop of `OmegaData` component is [] ... so my  question  is which of the component lifecycle methods I need to use and how to fix this kind of ploblems ?

Comment: requests and so .. are best to go on componentDidMount. although in your case after the results is changed the omegaData props will change causing it to re-render.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem as-is.  When you `setState` in the parent component `OmegaData` will be re-rendered with the correct props.  If `OmegaData` will not render correctly without the *real* data then you can do one of two things:

```
// 1. Render null or a spinner until the data is ready
render() {
  const results = this.state.results;
  if (results.length > 0) {
    return <OmegaData results={results} />;
  } else {
    return null; // or a spinner, or whatever makes sense
  }
}
```

or

```
// 2. Teach OmegaData to render correctly
class OmegaData extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.results.map(result => {
      return <div>This is a result: {result}</div>;
    });
  }
}

OmegaData.defaultProps = {
  results: []
};
```